# Unique solution for $\int_x^1 f(t) dt = 2x$ and $|x| < \epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-verification

Let $f$ be continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$f(0) \neq -2 \quad\text{ and } \quad \int_0^1 f(t) = 0.$$
Show that there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that the equation 
$$\int_x^1 f(t) dt =  2x$$
has a unique solution for $|x|<\epsilon$.

I was able to show that it has a unique solution when given $x$ is either positive or negative. Given $f$ is even, I could not show if $x$ is a solution, then $-x$ is not a solution.

**My solution:** 
First assume that $x>0$, to find a solution for the above problem, it suffices to solve the following 
$$\int_0^x f(t) dt = -2x$$
since $\int_0^x f + \int_x^1 f = \int_0^1 f = 0$.

Now given $f(0) \neq -2$, let us assume that $f(0) > -2$. Denote 
$x_* : = \text{ the infimum of all positive solutions}$, we must have 
$$f(x_*) < -2,$$
we can see this by rewriting the problem as
$$\int_0^x f(t) +2 dt = 0.$$

Now to show the existence of $\epsilon$ for the unique solution, it suffices to show that the set of positive solutions can not contain an interval such as $(x_*, b)$. Argue by contradiction, suppose $\int_0^x f(t) dt = -2x$ for each $x\in (x_*, b)$, then the derivatives are also equal, that is 
$f(x)= -2$ for each $x\in (x_*, b)$, by continuity of $f$, we have $f(x_*) = 2$ which is a contradiction. Thus there exists an $\epsilon$ such that the problem has a unique solution $x_*\in (0,\epsilon)$.

Now for $x<0$, the problem can be rewritten as 
$$\int_x^0 f(t) dt = 2x$$
since $\int_0^1 f = 0$.

Now assume $f$ is an even function, isn't this equivalent with $\int_0^x f = -2x$ for $x>0$?

Shouldn't $-x_*$ also be a solution? So $|x| <\epsilon$ would have two solutions...

Thank you very much!

**Edit:** I see there might be a problem with my solution, that is I assumed $x_* <1$, I will try to fix this first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $g(x)=\int_x^1f(t)dt-2x$, then $g(0)=0$ and $g'(0)\ne0$, and consequently $g'$ keeps a constant sign on $(-\epsilon,+\epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon>0$. This proves that $g$ is strictly monotonous in this interval. Thus, the equation $g(x)=0$ has
a unique solution in  $(-\epsilon,+\epsilon)$ which is clearly $x_*=0$.